# Reverse DNS for my elastic IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, reverse-dns

We hosted our website over Amazon EC2 but now we are facing problem in delivering mails to yahoo and hotmail but Gmail is fine.

But as per my knowledge this might be due to reverse DNS lookup.

i also got a good explanation [here](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/sending-email-from-ec2.html)

but now when i am trying to fill the form(you can refer this link for detail https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=624) at Amazon for reverse dns for my elastic IP then it will ask me to provide a IP address for my Elastic IP and that IP address is used for reverse DNS look up.

So now i am confused which IP address i should provide in that from.

SO please help me on this issue.

-Thanks

P.S.

I also find a reverse DNS address after entering my elastic IP at http://lookupserver.com/ can i use that address at amazon for reverse DNS lookup.

Comment: let say my eip is `1.2.3.4` what should i enter in the field `Reverse DNS Record for EIP 1` shal it be in the form of `ec2-1-2-3-4..ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Elastic IP Address is an IP address.   It's that simple.  No translation is needed.  Use the Elastic IP address that you have associated with the instance sending your emails.

If you don't have an Elastic IP address allocated, you'll want to take care of this before filling out the form.

To get even better deliverability from EC2, look into using the relatively new SES (Simple Email Service).

Comment: let say my eip is `1.2.3.4` what should i enter in the field `Reverse DNS Record for EIP 1` shal it be in the form of `ec2-1-2-3-4..ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: The Reverse DNS prompt is for customers who want to return their own host/domain name when servers receiving email from you run a reverse DNS to see what host sent the email. They tend to follow that up immediately with a forward DNS to make sure that it returns that IP address, so don't forget to set that up, too.

Comment: yah thats correct but i hv very less knowledge about reverse DNS so i wanted to know that in case of EC2 will `ec2-1-2-3-4..ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com` be the reverse dns ?

Comment: The reverse DNS shouldn't be of the form *.compute.amazonaws.com, because that still doesn't help a blacklist from determining that your IP address actually matches the domain name you're publicly using. I have one of those rDNS records set up, and it's not enough, so I'm also trying to figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am looking for how to set the rDNS address of my elastic IP so that I can receive email.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/ complete the form at :

https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request